# SCRIPT438: SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'component'

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

We are trying build a SPA application using Laravel + vue + bootstrap.

we did follow this article: https://laravel-news.com/using-vue-router-laravel

but any component doesn't be load and in console we have an error:

```
SCRIPT438: SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'component'
```

app.js file:

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');
window.Vue = require('vue-router');

Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue'));
Vue.component('application-component', require('./components/Application.vue'));
Vue.component('about-us-component', require('./components/About-US.vue'));
Vue.component('contact-us-component', require('./components/Contact-US.vue'));

const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/',
            name: 'application',
            component: Application
        },
        {
            path: '/about-us',
            name: 'about-us',
            component: About-Us
        },
        {
            path: '/contact-us',
            name: 'contact-us',
            component: Contact-Us
        },
    ],
});

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: { Application },
    router,
});
```

where is the issue and how can we fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this work with you

```
var bootstrap = require('./bootstrap');

var Vue = require('vue');
var VueRouter = require('vue-router');
Vue.use(bootstrap);

var ExampleComponent = require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue');
var ApplicationComponent = require('./components/Application.vue');
var AboutUsComponent = require('./components/About-US.vue');
var ContactUsComponent = require('./components/Contact-US.vue');

const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/',
            name: 'application',
            component: ApplicationComponent
        },
        {
            path: '/about-us',
            name: 'about-us',
            component: AboutUsComponent
        },
        {
            path: '/contact-us',
            name: 'contact-us',
            component: ContactUsComponent
        },
    ],
});

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: { Application },
    router,
});
```

Comment: not works. error in console:  SCRIPT5009: SCRIPT5009: 'applicationComponent' is not defined

Comment: that's great, it means Vue installed & bootstrap too, so can you please add what's specific name of your all components?

Comment: not works. error in console:  SCRIPT445: SCRIPT445: Object doesn't support this action